# Getting a map() to return a list instead of map object in Python 3.x

Tags: python

I was trying to take the matrix sum of two matrices and I have used the below code. Program runs fine except I am getting output as map object and not the list. How to get a map object return a list.

#### CODE:

```
a,b,=[[1,2,4],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],[[1,2,4],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
c=[map(sum,zip(*t)) for t in zip(a,b)]
print(list(c))
```

#### *OUTPUT:*

```
[<map object at 0x00000208E89FB340>, <map object at 0x00000208E89FB370>, <map object at 0x00000208E89FB550>]
```

Comment: `list(map(blah, blah))`

Answer (score 2):

list evaluates map function by list(map(...)). How about below code?

```py
a,b = [[1,2,4], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]], [[1,2,4], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
c = [list(map(sum, zip(*t))) for t in zip(a,b)]  # [[2, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this is that `c` is already a list. To make items in `c` list instead of map objects. You can code like this:

```py
a, b = [[1,2,4],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], [[1,2,4],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
c = [list(map(sum,zip(*t))) for t in zip(a,b)]
print(c)
```

**Output:**

```
[[2, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6]]
```